# json query for each item [number] in a loop

Tags: jquery, json, loops

I have a two loops:
one to count objects from a page, and other to set to each object a variable.
let's say x is the number of objects and y the variables;
so eg.:

`for x=10 ; y=3`loop shold look like:

```
 x:y
    1:1
    2:2
    [..]
    8:2
    9:3
    10:1
```

For each object I need to make a json query. Json will reply with 0/1 meaning query was/was not successful, 
and if the response fails, the query has to ignore the y var:
eg.:

```
x:y
    1:1 //1
    2:2 //1
    3:3 //0 -   this is the failed query
    4:1 //1
    5:2 //1
    6:1 //1 -   y !=3 cause of failed query
```

......

```
    $('button.#start').click(function(){
        var last = $('input.blue').length;
        var totalpackages = '10';
        var currentpackage;
        for( currentpackage = '1'; currentpackage <= totalpackages; )
        {// for each package;
            var n;
            for(n='1'; n <= last;)
            {
                //alert(currentpackage + ' : ' + n)
                //n++
                //currentpackage++
                $.getJSON('api/testsenderfail.php', 
                function(data){
                    worklink = data.data;
                    if(worklink == '1')
                    {
                    alert(currentpackage + ' : ' + n + ' : ' + worklink)
                    n++
                    currentpackage++
                    }else{
                    alert(currentpackage + ' : ' + n + ' : ' + worklink)
                    n++
                    //currentpackage++
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    })
```

I am sure I did somethink wrong. Mozzila alerts "A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. 
You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete."

Php script  "api/testsenderfail.php" generates json array and outputs {"data":"1"} (0/1) 
90% outputs 1 and 10% outputs 0. 
This is for testing purposes.

```
<?php
    $rand = rand(0, 9);
    if($rand == '0'){$work = '0';}else{$work = '1';}
    $data = array('data' => $work);
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: I can't quite guess the use case from the question. But can't you just send all the data at once to one script? What is the requirement that made you look at that type of loop

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX call is asynchronous, which means that the callback methods will run after you have exited the click event handler. You are only changing the loop counters in the callback methods, and that can only happen after you have completed the loops, and that can only happen after you have changed the loop counters.

So, you have an eternal loop.

Comment: so i need to defin a loop fo each query? i can define a loop for x[my case], but i will need another loop that is dependent of json reply ... any other ideeas ?

Comment: or ... if i use synchronous call to ajax? sorry, but i`m newbie in this field.

Comment: then i think at another solution: the button handler starts one loop: x. how can i define variable to be userd outside of the function/button handler?

Comment: If you want the looping to be controlled by the result of the AJAX call, then you either have to use synchronous calls, or rebuild the code to use state instead of loops, so than the callback for one call sends the request for the next call. The latter would be preferrable, as it doesn't freeze the browser.

Answer (score 0):

i have found a way to do this easy. i will post in case anyone else is in same situation.

```
$('button.#start').click(
  function(){
    var X;
    for(X='1'; X <= lastX;){
      do_Y_vals(x, y) // here a loop to count X that will pass every X to another function  
      x++
      y++
    }
  })
```

inside this function query each X.
if he got reply, the function loops until y = lastY

```
function do_y_vals(x){
  $.getJSON(//variables here
    function(data){
      if(data.reply == '1'){
        function do_y_vals(x, y)
        y++
      }
    });
}
```